# How to open all files that starts with specific prefix in java?

Tags: java, file

Is there any way to open some of the text files in the directory that starts with a specific name in Java?

For example in my directory I have the following files:

```
Ab-01.txt
Ab-02.txt
Ab-03.txt
Ab-04.txt
SomethingElse.txt
NotRelated.txt
```

So now in my Java code I only want to open those files that starts with “`Ab-`“

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yes. Use [`File.listFiles(FilenameFilter)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28java.io.FilenameFilter%29):

As an example:

```
File dir = new File("/path/to/directory");
File[] foundFiles = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.startsWith("Ab-");
    }
});

for (File file : foundFiles) {
    // Process file
}
```

Of course, change the condition in the `accept()` method to whatever you need. So maybe `name.startsWith("Ab-") && name.endsWith(".txt")`.

Comment: You'll want to include a null check, such as `for(File file : Objects.requireNonNull(foundFiles)) {...`

Answer (score 6):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles(java.io.FilenameFilter)
use this method on the parent folder and implements the FilenameFilter like:

```
boolean accept(File dir, String name){
     return name.matches("AB-\n{2}.*")
}
```

Comment: I hate how google sometimes puts the 1.4 docs higher in the results than the 1.6 docs. Googling `file javadoc 6` seems the best bet.

Answer (score 1):

Create a java.io.File representing your directory, then use the [listFiles method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28java.io.FilenameFilter%29) that takes a [FileNameFilter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html). You can tell it exactly what pattern you want to match, such as name.startsWith("Ab-").

Answer (score 1):

```
File files[] = directory.listFiles();
for (File f : files) {
    if(//filename matches what you want)
    {   
        // do whatever you want with each  File f
    }
}
```

Should work