# How to get (Paths.get) one file with a filename starting with a certain character?

Tags: java

im working in java 8 project where i read one file from specific location using Paths class and all works fine.
this is my code :

```
String inputDir = "src/main/distribution/in";

String fileName = "my_file.txt";

Path inputFile = Paths.get(inputDir, fileName);

// reading file lines... is OK
```

now my issue is this file will be changed each day with the following format `filename.txt_date`
so each day i will find only one file with name like this : `my_file.txt_02082020`.

so my question is how i can read my file only by checking if the file name starts with "my_file.txt_"?

do you have any suggestion to do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666872/how-to-open-all-files-that-starts-with-specific-prefix-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Path comes with streams so you can filter on the list of files:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

String inputDir = "src/main/distribution/in";
String fileName = "my_file.txt";
Optional<Path> file=Files.list(Paths.get(inputDir))
    .filter(p->p.getFileName().toFile().getName().startsWith(fileName))
    .findFirst();
if(file.isPresent())
{
    Path foundFile=file.get();
    File asFile=foundFile.toFile();
    // business logic here
}
```

EDIT: used findFirst instead of forEach as there is only one file.

EDIT2: apparently Path.startsWith() does not work the same way as String. Changed it to get the filename as a string (via File) to verify its name.

Comment: [findFirst](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst()) might be a better choice than forEach.

Comment: Thank you @Conffusion , but i have a question , how i can get my File Object inside this loop instead of just printing the msg? because in my code i have this stringArray = Files.readAllLines(inputFile, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1); to get the content of the file

Comment: p is of type Path en p.toFile() is your File instance. (Lambda expressions are less clear than plane old java)

Comment: file.isPresent() returns true only if flieName = the exact file name , in my case if i gave it "my_file.txt_20082020" file.isPresent returns true , if i gave it "my_file.text_" (this is what im looking for) it returns false ,do you have any idea on how to verify the file existing using startwiths correctly. thanks in advance :)

Comment: The filter checks on startsWith(fileName). if there is a file starting with "my_file.txt_" findFirst will return the file in an Optional instance. findFirst() always returns an Optional instance. Optional.isPresent() is used to check if there is actually a hit. `isPresent()`is a method of Optional to verify it contains an instance or not. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#isPresent--

Comment: yes i know how Optional works, im getting java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present , that's mean the condition dosen't find any file starts with "my_file_txt" , but in my folder  i have a file with the name "my_file_txt_20082020"

Comment: Had a second look after your remark and you're right: Path.startsWith() is only true if a complete section of the path corresponds, not just a substring. Sorry for the confusion :)

Comment: no problem your pseudonyme is conffusion :D , im just kidding , anyway thank you so much you gave me an idea on how to achieve this.

Comment: In fact conffusion was a first attempt to write a library to combine multiple ways of storing configuration parameters (database tables, properties files,...) but accessing them using a single API. so conffusion=configuration +fusion. Good luck